# Ordering the data based on 2 columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame x with columns a,b,c.

I am trying to order the data based on columns a and c and my ordering criteria is ascending on a and descending on c. Below is the code I wrote.

```
z <- x[order(x$a,-x$c),]
```

This code gives me a warning as below.

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x$c) : - not meaningful for factors
```

Also, when I check the data frame z using head(z), it gives me wrong data as below:

```
30708908 0.3918980    NA
22061768 0.4022183    NA
21430343 0.4118651    NA
21429828 0.4134888    NA
21425966 0.4159323    NA
22057521 0.4173094    NA
```

and initially there wasnt any NA values of the column c in the data frame x. I have gone through a lot of threads but couldn't find any solution. Can anybody please suggest.

Comment: One of your  columns is a factor. Try `str(x)`. You can convert to numeric (assuming nothing funky is going on) via `as.factor(as.character(x))`. I also suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Do you mean `as.numeric(as.character(x))` rather than `as.factor`?

Comment: Mea culpa, yes I mean `numeric`. Time to go back to bed. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
install.packages('plyr');
library('plyr');
z<-arrange(x,a,desc(c));
```

In addition, you can use the

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

before you create your frame, or while creating your 'x' data frame, specify

```
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
```

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: I tried using the above mentioned method after using stringsAsFactors=FALSE option. It again gave me NA with the below warning message:

top<-x[order(x$a,-as.numeric(as.character(x$c)) ), ]

In order(x$a, -as.numeric(as.character(x$c))) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

head(top)
             a  b  c
30708908 0.3918980    NA
22061768 0.4022183    NA
21430343 0.4118651    NA
21429828 0.4134888    NA
21425966 0.4159323    NA
22057521 0.4173094    NA

Comment: Using arrange also gave me NAs.

library("plyr");

z<-arrange(x,a,desc(c))
> head(z)
      a  b c
1 0.3918980    NA
2 0.4022183    NA
3 0.4118651    NA
4 0.4134888    NA
5 0.4159323    NA
6 0.4173094    NA

Comment: @DWin: I tried using the above mentioned method after using stringsAsFactors=FALSE option. It again gave me NA with the below warning message: top<-x[order(x$a,-as.numeric(as.character(x$c)) ), ]
In order(x$a, -as.numeric(as.character(x$c))) : NAs introduced by coercion
head(top)
a  b c 
30708908 0.3918980 NA 
22061768 0.4022183 NA 
21430343 0.4118651 NA 
21429828 0.4134888 NA 
21425966 0.4159323 NA 
22057521 0.4173094 NA

Answer (score 1):

```
z <- x[order(x$a,-as.character(x$c) ), ]
z
```

If as Roman suspects you have digits in your facttor levels you may need to do as he suggests and add `as.numeric`, otherwise `9` will be greater than `10`

```
z <- x[order(x$a,-as.numeric(as.character(x$c)) ), ]
z
```

But if they are characters, then you will again get all NAs, so it really depends on the nature of the levels of `x$c`